# System not declared in scope?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I know its simple code, How do I fix "System not declared in scope" problem?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    system ( "TITLE Calculator" );
    system ( "COLOR 2" );
    char cChar;
    double dfirstnumber;
    double dsecondnumber;
    char cDoagain;

    do
    {
        system("CLS");
        cout << "Please enter the first number you would like to use."<< endl;
        cin >> dfirstnumber;
        cout<< "Please enter the operation you would like to perform." << " (+,-,*,or /)" << endl;
        cin >> cChar;
        cout<< "Please enter the second number you would like to use." << endl;
        cin >> dsecondnumber;

        switch (cChar)
        {
            case '+':
                cout << "The answer is: " << dfirstnumber << "+" << dsecondnumber << "=" <<
                (dfirstnumber + dsecondnumber) << endl;
                break;
            case '-':
                cout << "The answer is: " << dfirstnumber << "-" << dsecondnumber << "=" <<
                (dfirstnumber - dsecondnumber) << endl;
                break;
            case '*':
                cout << "The answer is: " << dfirstnumber << "*" << dsecondnumber << "=" <<
                (dfirstnumber * dsecondnumber) << endl;
                break;
            case 'x':
                cout << "The answer is: " << dfirstnumber << "x" << dsecondnumber << "=" <<
                (dfirstnumber * dsecondnumber) << endl;
                break;
            case 'X':
                cout << "The answer is: " << dfirstnumber << "X" << dsecondnumber << "=" <<
                (dfirstnumber * dsecondnumber) << endl;
                break;
            case '/':
                if(dsecondnumber == 0){
                cout<< "That is an invalid operation." << endl;}
                else{
                cout << "The answer is: " << dfirstnumber << "/" << dsecondnumber << "=" <<
                (dfirstnumber / dsecondnumber) << endl;

        }
                break;
                default:
                    cout << "That is an invalid operation." << endl;
                    break;
    }
                cout << "Would you like to start again? (Y/N)" << endl;
                cin >>  cDoagain;
    }while (cDoagain == 'Y' or cDoagain == 'y');
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Heres my end message:

> C:\Documents and Settings\Nilo\My Documents\Work\Testing\main.cpp||In
>   function 'int main()':| C:\Documents and Settings\Nilo\My
>   Documents\Work\Testing\main.cpp|8|error: 'system' was not declared in
>   this scope||
>
> |=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|

Comment: what is `    system ( "TITLE Calculator" );
    system ( "COLOR 2" );` supposed to be doing, cos system isn't an in built function

Answer (score 56):

You need to add:

```
 #include <cstdlib>
```

in order for the compiler to see the prototype for `system()`.

Comment: If using C it is #include <stdlib.h>

Comment: @Doug: sure, but the question is tagged `C++`

Comment: @PaulR Still, it's helpful for a bunch of people. :)

Answer (score 14):

Chances are that you've not included the header file that declares `system()`.

In order to be able to compile C++ code that uses functions which you don't (manually) declare yourself, you have to pull in the declarations. These declarations are normally stored in so-called header files that you pull into the current translation unit using the `#include` preprocessor directive. As the code does not `#include` the header file in which `system()` is declared, the compilation fails.

To fix this issue, find out which header file provides you with the declaration of `system()` and include that. As mentioned in several other answers, you most likely want to add `#include <cstdlib>`